# how to have R opencpu interact with php

Tags: php, r, opencpu

I am new to php and have some experience with R [opencpu](https://www.opencpu.org/).

Suppose I use localhost (127.0.0.1) to host my opencpu with the (default) port of 8004. Then, I cannot run the Apache using the same port. Instead, I have to run it in another port, say 8080. Then all my .php will be held on a server of the port 8080.

So how can I connect my .php files when running a opencpu app?

I thought that I could put my .php files in `inst/www`, where my `index.html` is. However, when I do so and open the page of `http://localhost/ocpu/library/.../www/xxx.php`, my browser automatically downloads the .php file but not executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to ensure your web server is configured to properly serve PHP, which is a [whole other thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page). However, if you're only accessing files on localhost then you can just execute the PHP files directly using the [`system2()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/system2) command.

```
output <- system2('php', c('/path/to/script.php', 'arg1', 'arg2'), stdout=TRUE)
```

Setting `stdout=TRUE` ensures the output from the script is returned for later use.